# Facebook API: Getting user's details

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My application gets users' locations from Facebook and stores them in the database. The way I get those is by making a call to

```
$this->facebook->api('/user_id');
```

but for that to work I need the user with **user_id** to be logged in and executing the script.

What if I want my application to update their location once every day? How do I do that? If I make a call to

```
$this->facebook->api('/user_id');
```

without being authenticated as the user with id **user_id**, then I only get public info. Is there any way to get their private info, granted that they provided access to the application?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to store the `access_token` associated with that user, and retrieve that access_token to make requests when you need to update information. To do this, take the short-lived token you received when they logged in, and exchange it for a long-lived token that lasts 60 days via this call:

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id={app-id}&
    client_secret={app-secret}&
    fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

Read this doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/